# Unbiased estimator and sufficient statistics

Tags: self-study, estimation, inference, unbiased-estimator, sufficient-statistics

> Let $X_1,..,X_n$ be a random sample of $f(x;\theta)=\theta
>  x^{\theta-1}I_{[0,1]}(x)$
>
> Find a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ and construct a unbiased
>   estimator for $\theta$ as a function of sufficient statistics and
>   verify that it is efficient.

Comment: No, $\sum \log(X_i)$ is not distributed as a Ga$(n,\theta)$.

Comment: Note that $\log(X_i)$ is negative!

Comment: @Glen_b Now that I've seen that $log(0)=-\infty$ , but the statistics I found is sufficient right? I can do it $f_n(x;\theta)=\theta^n e^{-(1-\theta)(-\sum logX)}$ and take $T(X)=-\sum log X$ is $Gamma(n,\theta)$?

Comment: Sounds like you're getting close.

Comment: Rather than asking incremental questions, you should put more effort into solving the problem. For instance, since you know the pdf of $X_i$, deriving the pdf of $-\log(X_i)$ should not be immensely difficult. From there, if you identify a standard distribution [and you should!], checking the distribution of the sum should follow from Wikipedia or standard textbooks. And then you would know enough about the moments of $T$ to identify an unbiased estimator.

Comment: @Xi'an I think now I could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a sufficient statistic is $T(x)=-\sum \log{X}$ and -$\sum\log{X}\sim \text{Gamma}(n,\theta)$

Then I call $Y=-\sum logX$
$$E[\frac{1}{Y}]=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{y}\frac{\theta^ny^{n-1}e^{-\theta y}dy}{\Gamma(n)}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\theta^ny^{n-2}e^{-\theta y}dy}{\Gamma(n)}$$
$$=\frac{\theta}{n-1}\int_0^\infty \frac{\theta^{n-1}y^{n-2}e^{-\theta y}dy}{\Gamma(n-1)}=\frac{\theta}{n-1}$$

So the unbiased estimator is $\hat{\theta}=\frac{n-1}{T}$